# Why npm install is getting stuck for so long? It can't even finish

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, wsl-2

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in wsl2.
And npm keeps getting stuck, when I need to install a package.

I have found a way around it,
to change the **nameserver to 8.8.8.8** in /etc/resolv.conf file.

But, everytime I log into my system, i need to do that.

Is there any solution, and why /etc/resolv.conf file keep changing?

Comment: This is a distro/network-specific problem. Your ISP is probably blocking some DNSes. I live in Iran and I have similar problems without using VPNs. Ubuntu uses NetworkManager library for managing networks. Check https://serverfault.com/questions/810636/how-to-manage-dns-in-networkmanager-via-console-nmcli

Comment: Okay, how do I make it work all the time for all applications? Like npm, wget.. all should be able to resolve the dns servers?

Comment: If using google DNS servers solves the problem, yes., changing your system DNS servers should solve the problem for all the apps. The linked post's answers show how you can change DNS servers. The issue can also be a miss-configuration and not necessarily DNS blocking.